# how to obtain Google Bigquery FQDN Project ID

Tags: google-bigquery, fqdn

I am working with a customer who is using Google BigQuery, and we are attempting to reverse-engineer their model. The problem is that the connection requires the Project Id in a FQDN form, which usually comes to mydomain.com:myProject

I am not familiar at all with BigQuery, is there a place in the users dashboard i can find this? Everything we have browsed through only seems to give us the Project ID.

Answer (score 1):

GCP [Bigquery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery) represents a concept of Enterprise data [warehouse](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/bigquery-data-warehouse), which is  isolated and GCP fully-managed environment for high-scalable operations addressing data analytics tasks. Although GCP Bigquery conceptually built as serverless platform **Software as a Service** (SaaS) providing an execution environment for customer analytics purposes, infrastructure and hardware components are self managed by Google cloud computing inventory, that means that Bigquery service doesn't offer any regular hosting endpoint for external visitors.

The interaction with GCP Bigquery can be only established in the following ways:

- BigQuery [web UI](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-web-ui) in the Cloud Console;
- Using BigQuery [command-line](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool) tool;
- Bigquery [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest) through service endpoint:
  https://bigquery.googleapis.com;
- Using programming language specific Cloud Client [Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) for
  the BigQuery API.